# How to prevent my main screen being activated before pushed to the navigator?

Tags: flutter, widget, lifecycle

My app starts with the onboarding screen which bears a (ENTER) button for the user to tap on to… enter.

This routes them to the BLE radar screen which scans for our devices lineup around and allows for connection to any known device.

In the BLE radar screen (a stateful widget) I added a post frame callback which fires the BLE devices scan process as follows (a stripped own version of course):

```dart
class _BleRadarState extends StateMixin<BleRadar> {

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Now scan for BLE devices, once the first build has been completed
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => startScan());
  }
}
```

But unfortunately, while declaring my routes from the `MyApp` (it is my topmost app screen), the `BleRadar` widget is actually created and the post frame performed.

Here is a stripped down version of `MyApp`widget:

```dart
///
/// The app
///
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Consumer<ThemeModel>(
      builder: (context, themeModel, child) => MaterialApp(

              // == Run onboarding screen first, from which a OK button routes
              // to "/" (Ble radar screen)

              initialRoute: '/onboarding',

              routes: {
                Global.routeBleRadar: (context) => BleRadar(),
                '/onboarding': (context) => OnboardingScreen(),
              }));
}
```

Therefore, when the user taps on the (ENTER) button, a new `BleRadar` instance is created and then again the `startScan` is performed which causes an exception to be thrown as the `flutter_blue_plus` can naturally run only one scan at a time.

Listening at the scanning stream is of no help: when the `BleRadar` instance  is disposed, it cancels the subscription.

Prior to fix the issue by trying to handle the scanning subscription higher at the `MyApp` level, I wonder if there is a nicer, better solution?